# nsis - Log names of files to be copied using detailprint

Tags: logging, nsis

I'm trying to create an installer with NSIS for a Software I'm developing. 

I want to copy all the files in the folder. So use '*.*' to copy.

```
File /r "${TARGETDIR}\Bin\*.*"
```

I want to log detailprint to see what files are in the folder. 
(If there are other methods besides detailprint Other things are fine)

Please let me know if you know how to log which files you copy.

Comment: I thought it listed the filenames during extraction? Or are you talking about something else? Also, are you using normal or solid compression?